# Retrieving and persisting state across requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am writing my first ASP.NET Web API application. I am familiar with other web application frameworks (mostly Symfony, but also Django, and to a lesser extent RoR).

I am struggling a bit, to understand the sequence of events that occur after a request is sent from a browser/front end client, to the web server.

I am writing a multi tenanted application, which uses a DB backend. I am using ADO and raw SQL to access the database, I also need to store a lot of information, per user, so that basically, I create (or fetch from cache), a preloaded context, for the user.

here is some pseudo-code, that illustrates, what I'm trying to achieve, in ASP.NET.

```
namespace myApp.Controllers
{
    public class FoobarController : ApiController
    {
        public Response doLogin(request)
        {
             var ctx = myApplicationContext.getInstance();
             var user = ctx.getUser();     

             if (!user.isLoggedOn())
             {
                 username = request.getParameter('username');
                 password= request.getParameter('password');

                 dbManager = ctx.getDbInstance();

                 resp = dbManager.internalLogin(username, password);

                 // Load permissions etc for current user, from db
                 // Store user info in cache ..
             }
        }       

        public Response ActionOne(request)
        {
             ctx = myApplicationContext.getInstance();
             user = ctx.getUser();

             if (user.hasPermission('xxx'))
             {

             }
        }
    }
}
```

My question, is, how do I implement this kind of functionality:

Namely:

- Create an application context, in which I can populate with context sensitive information like a database connection, mailer configuration, object factories, miscellaneous state information etc.
- Access a user object (which I can add user credentials, permissions etc to)
- Have access to session variables etc?

**Notes**

1. I will be deploying the web app on Linux, and I will be using Apache as the web server.
2. For the purpose of this project, I don't want to use any Microsoft technology like Azure, Windows Authentications etc (other than C# and ASP.Net)
3. I want to use a raw database connection, not using Entity Manager (legacy application port)

Comment: Have you looked into OWIN and ASP Identity? Identity comes with the template of ASP applications these days, as does OWIN, and it'll handle all your auth needs. OWIN is a more basic framework on which everything else (theoretically) sits--if you're looking to build your own auth framework just for learning, I'd start off with OWIN. There are some tutorials on the ASP.net website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am struggling a bit, to understand the sequence of events that occur after a request is sent from a browser/front end client, to the web server.

For this I would say [this PDF Poster](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) gives best pictorial representation of request processing in ASP.NET WebAPI.

> My question, is, how do I implement this kind of functionality:
>
> Namely:
>
> - Create an application context, in which I can populate with context
>     sensitive information like a database connection, mailer
>     configuration, object factories, miscellaneous state information etc.
> - Access a user object (which I can add user credentials, permissions etc to)
> - Have access to session variables etc?

For this I would say, WebAPIs are designed to be stateless and so, best approach is to create a persistent session (Say in database) and use an identifier for session (like session key or token) for each request to identify a user and fetch his session variables / context informations.

Now, for implementing the kind of functionality you have asked for in your example, that would be attained by a combination of Authentication Filters and Authorization Filters([More details on implementing them here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)) .

Each request in WebAPI is first processed by handlers and then before execution of requested action, filters are applied. For your example Authentication filters will hold the `DoLogin` function and `user.hasPermission` logic will reside in Authorization filters and only action logic will reside in the Action(function) in controller.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I was already aware of that pdf schematic. Unfortunately, it does not help much, as it assumes that the reader is already familiar with ASP.Net classes/namespaces etc. What I was looking for was a diagram that mapped concepts in the workflow to framework classes - The diagram as it stands, looks over engineered IMHO. Failing all that, it would at least be useful to see how I can write my own authentication and authorisation filters.

Comment: Truely speaking thats what the diagram looked to me as well at the first glance. But once I got basic understanding of webAPI, this turnout to be a one stop point for any clarification I need for myself. This link gives more details of implementing authorization and authentication. I'll update this in my answer as well. - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api